How to Convert Date with Customize timezone in Java
I have a date with local PC timezone(e.g India). And I want to convert to Singapore Time and set it with Date Type.
This is my source.
Date inputTime = new Date(); // input Date with local PC timezone (India)

ZonedDateTime d = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(inputTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = d.format(formatter);
Date date = Date.from(d.toInstant());

I have to return Date Type.
But After setting to Date , the date is changed to India Date Time and save it to database.
I want to save Asia/Singapore datatime to database.

Date doesn't have a time zone. It's crucial that you understand that. (And ideally, move away from java.util.Date entirely.) See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Use [code block] format for code, logs and text information.

I don’t think you can fix this with the poorly designed and long outdated Date class. Instead save a LocalDateTime to your database. A LocalDateTime hasn’t got a time zone and won’t be influenced by the time zone settings of your JVM nor of your database session. Even better use timestamp with time zone (or equivalent) in your database and OffsetDateTime in UTC in Java, which will then be saved in UTC in your database, which is generally considered good practice.

As pointed out in comment that "Date doesn't have a time zone."
To achieve your output you'll need to perform several steps carefully. The core issue you are facing is that the Date class in Java does not store any time zone information; it only represents an instant in time. Thus, when you convert it back to a Date object after formatting, it will inherently reflect the local time zone of your system (in this case, India) because Date does not have time zone awareness.
Here’s how you can address this issue:
Steps to Correctly Convert and Save the Date in a Different Time Zone
Convert the Local Date to Singapore Time Zone:

Use ZonedDateTime to convert the date to the desired time zone.
Convert the Singapore Time Zone Date Back to Date:

Convert the ZonedDateTime back to Date using the toInstant() method.
Ensure the Date is Saved Correctly in the Database:

When saving the date to the database, make sure that the date-time is stored correctly. Ensure that your database column is set to store the date-time in UTC or any other standardized format to avoid timezone issues.

Example Code
     Date inputTime = new Date(); 

    // Convert Date to ZonedDateTime in local timezone (India)
    ZonedDateTime indiaTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(inputTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

    // Convert India ZonedDateTime to Singapore ZonedDateTime
    ZonedDateTime singaporeTime = indiaTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore"));

    // Format Singapore time to a String if needed (optional)
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = singaporeTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println("Formatted Singapore Time: " + formattedDate);

    // Convert Singapore ZonedDateTime back to Date
    Date dateInSingapore = Date.from(singaporeTime.toInstant());

    // Print to verify the result
    System.out.println( "inputTime.toString() = " + inputTime );
    System.out.println( "dateInSingapore.toString() = " + dateInSingapore );

When run:
Formatted Singapore Time: 2024-08-04 04:22:13
inputTime.toString() = Sat Aug 03 20:22:13 UTC 2024
dateInSingapore.toString() = Sat Aug 03 20:22:13 UTC 2024


Alternative syntax: inputTime.toInstant().atZone( z )

You have the right idea, but the expression is a bit misleading. For one thing, it is not the java.util.Date object that "reflect the local time zone" — It is the java.util.Date#toString method that applies JVM’s current default time zone while generating text. And, the statement "Date does not have time zone awareness" is not quite right – java.util.Date is aware of a single time zone, or offset actually: An offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. To be truly unaware of zones/offsets would be the java.time.LocalDateTime class, but legacy date-time classes have no equivalent.
